# Got error when trying to "impl pallet_balances::Config for Test" at pallets/template/src/mock.rs

Tags: pallet

[image]
As the picture shows, when I try to "impl pallet_balances::Config for Test" of pallets/template/src/mock.rs, I got the error "type mismatch resolving `<mock::Test as frame_system::Config>::AccountData == AccountData<u128>`". I tried to do the fix as the compiler note says, but still got errors. So could I know what's wrong with my code? I'm using polkadot-9.25 branch, and below is my code at pallets/template/src/mock.rs:

```
use crate as pallet_template;
// use frame_support::traits::{ConstU16, ConstU64};
pub use frame_support::{
    construct_runtime, parameter_types,
    traits::{
        ConstU128, ConstU16, ConstU32, ConstU64, ConstU8, KeyOwnerProofSystem, Randomness,
        StorageInfo,
    },
    weights::{
        constants::{BlockExecutionWeight, ExtrinsicBaseWeight, RocksDbWeight, WEIGHT_PER_SECOND},
        IdentityFee, Weight,
    },
    StorageValue,
};
use frame_system as system;
use sp_core::H256;
use sp_runtime::{
    testing::Header,
    traits::{BlakeTwo256, IdentityLookup},
};

type UncheckedExtrinsic = frame_system::mocking::MockUncheckedExtrinsic<Test>;
type Block = frame_system::mocking::MockBlock<Test>;
type Balance = u128;

// Configure a mock runtime to test the pallet.
frame_support::construct_runtime!(
    pub enum Test where
        Block = Block,
        NodeBlock = Block,
        UncheckedExtrinsic = UncheckedExtrinsic,
    {
        System: frame_system::{Pallet, Call, Config, Storage, Event<T>},
        TemplateModule: pallet_template::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Event<T>},
        Balances: pallet_balances::{Pallet, Call, Storage, Config<T>, Event<T>},

    }
);

impl system::Config for Test {
    type BaseCallFilter = frame_support::traits::Everything;
    type BlockWeights = ();
    type BlockLength = ();
    type DbWeight = ();
    type Origin = Origin;
    type Call = Call;
    type Index = u64;
    type BlockNumber = u64;
    type Hash = H256;
    type Hashing = BlakeTwo256;
    type AccountId = u64;
    type Lookup = IdentityLookup<Self::AccountId>;
    type Header = Header;
    type Event = Event;
    type BlockHashCount = ConstU64<250>;
    type Version = ();
    type PalletInfo = PalletInfo;
    type AccountData = ();
    type OnNewAccount = ();
    type OnKilledAccount = ();
    type SystemWeightInfo = ();
    type SS58Prefix = ConstU16<42>;
    type OnSetCode = ();
    type MaxConsumers = frame_support::traits::ConstU32<16>;
}

impl pallet_template::Config for Test {
    type Event = Event;
}

impl pallet_balances::Config for Test {
    type MaxLocks = ConstU32<50>;
    type MaxReserves = ();
    type ReserveIdentifier = [u8; 8];
    /// The type for recording an account's balance.
    type Balance = Balance;
    /// The ubiquitous event type.
    type Event = Event;
    type DustRemoval = ();
    type ExistentialDeposit = ConstU128<500>;
    type AccountStore = System;
    type WeightInfo = pallet_balances::weights::SubstrateWeight<Test>;
}

// Build genesis storage according to the mock runtime.
pub fn new_test_ext() -> sp_io::TestExternalities {
    system::GenesisConfig::default().build_storage::<Test>().unwrap().into()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the reason now, I should change the type AccountData = () to    type AccountData = pallet_balances::AccountData

Comment: type AccountData = pallet_balances::AccountData<Balance>;